What is the opinion of Kashmiri shaivism on Ithihasas and Puranas?
Various Vedanta Sampradayas consider Ithihasas to be a valid pramana and accept the Puranas which belong to their sects i.e., Vaishnava sampradayas agree with vaishnava Puranas and so on. Since Kashmiri shaivism is based on Bhairava Agamas, I would like to know its interpretation of Ithihasas and Puranas.
